# Guardar usuario + puntos finalización partida

Tags: javascript

He hecho un juego de frontón. Obtengo el nombre del usuario mediante un prompt al iniciar la partida y lo guardo sin problemas en el localstorage.

> Mi problema se presenta al finalizar la partida no consigo que me
>   almacene los puntos, que necesito asociarlos a ese usuario y poder
>   comprobar si vuelve a jugar. Quizás mediante un array asociativo? Pero
>   no sé solucionarlo.

---

### CÓDIGO HTML/CSS

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>pong</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="satur">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css"> -->
        <style type="text/css">
        #cos {
            background-color: black;}
        .juego {
            background-color: #000000; border: 1px solid white; width : 600px; height: 400px; margin-top: 50px; margin-left: 40px;}
        .pelota{ 
            position: absolute; width: 20px; height: 20px; top: 30px; left: 30px; background-color: white;}
        .raqueta {
            position: absolute;width: 20px;height: 80px;background-color: white;margin-left: 10px;}
        .info {
            width: 600px;height: 150px;padding: 3px;background-color: white;border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;border: 1px solid white;margin-left: 40px;}
        .textoestatico {
            color: black; font: 20px arial, sans-serif; }
        .titol {
            color: black; font: 40px arial, sans-serif; }
        #instruccions {
            margin-top: 10px; color: white; font: 15px arial, sans-serif; margin-left: 50px; }
    </head>

<body id="cos"  onkeydown="mover(event);" onkeyup="parar(event);">
    <div >
        <div class="juego">
            <div class="pelota" id="pelota"></div>
            <div class="raqueta" id="jugador"></div>
        </div>

        <table class="info">
            <th> <h2 class="titol"> JOC DEL PONG </h2> </th>
            <tr>
                <td  align="center"><span class="textoestatico"> Puntuació</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center"><span class="textoestatico" id="puntosJugador">0</span></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div id="instruccions">
            <br/>
            <table>
              <tr>
                  <th>TECLES DEL JOC</th>
              </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td >Pujar > </td>
                    <td>Fletxa Up</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Baixar > </td>
                    <td> Fletxa Down </td>
                  </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="myjavascript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

código js

---

```
/*     LOCALSTORAGE  NOMBRE USUARIO + PUNTUACION    */

 window.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
    console.log("All resources finished loading!");
  });

var nombre;
// funcion que almacena el nombre usuario (introducido por prompt) y su puntuación
function usuari() {
    nombre=prompt('Introdueix el teu nick per començar el joc :', 'nom');

    localStorage.setItem('nomUsuari', nombre);
    localStorage.setItem('resultatPunts', puntuacion);

    var nomUsuari = localStorage.getItem('nomUsuari');
    var resultatEmmagatzemat = localStorage.getItem('resultatPunts');

    if (nombre == nomUsuari) {
       alert("Hola " + nomUsuari + ", aquesta és la teva puntuació anterior: " + resultatEmmagatzemat + " punts. " );  
     // actualitzar(); 
    }

    for(var i=0, t=localStorage.length; i < t; i++) {   //recorremos con un array los valores guardados en LocalStorage
    nomUsuari = localStorage.nomUsuari[i];
        if (nombre == nomUsuari ){
             alert('usuari: ' + nomUsuari + "te" + localStorage.puntuacio[i] + "punts");
        } 
    } 
}

  //Funció que actualitza la puntuació o no
function actualitzar(){
    var missatge = confirm("Vol que s'actualitzi la teva puntuació?");
    if (missatge){
        alert("S'actualitzarà la teva puntuació!");

    }else {
        localStorage.removeItem('resultatPunts');
    }
} 


/* ///////////////// variables globales ///////////////////////  */ 

// coordenadas x=0, y=0 del tablero
var ceroX = 50; // posicion izquierda del tablero (div) 
var ceroY = 50; // posicion superior del (div)

var paredX = 600 + ceroX; // PARED DE LA DERECHA el div tiene 600 de ancho, le sumamos el margen izq pantalla (50)
var paredY = 400 + ceroY; 
var velocidad = 3; //variable de la velocidad del juego
var puntuacion = 0; //inicializamos la puntuacion en 0

//guardamos por variables el acceso al DOM de la puntuacion (id="puntosJugador")
var puntos = document.getElementById("puntosJugador");  //acceso al elemento


/*  ///////////////// FUNCIONES GLOBALES ///////////////////////  */

//Obtener la posicion x de cualquier elemento mediante el acceso a su id al ser llamada
    function getX(id) {
        var objeto = document.getElementById(id); 
        var posicion= objeto.style.left;  // accedemos a la propiedad LEFT css (y) del objeto 
                                          // Nos devuelve un valor tipo string  "450px" por ejemplo
        var longitud = posicion.length;     //nos da la longitud del texto q hay en pos
        posicion = posicion.substring (0, longitud-2); //con este substring le quitamos el text "px" a posicion
        posicion = parseInt (posicion); // convertimos el texto en un numero
        return posicion;
    }

// funcion para obtener la posicion Y de nuestro elemento 
    function getY(id) {
        var objeto = document.getElementById(id); 
        var posicion= objeto.style.top;  //al acceder a la posicion de x , accedemos a sus propiedades css TOP.
                                          // Nos devuelve un valor tipo string  "450px" por ejemplo
        var longitud = posicion.length;     //nos da la longitud del texto q hay en pos
        posicion = posicion.substring (0, longitud-2); //con este substring le quitamos el text "px" a posicion
        posicion = parseInt(posicion); // convertimos el texto en un numero
        return posicion;
    }

// nos permite colocar cualquier elemento en la pantalla (BOLA, PALA)
    function colocarXY (id,x,y) {   
        var objeto = document.getElementById(id); 
         objeto.style.left = x + "px"; 
         objeto.style.top = y + "px"; 
    }

//PELOTA
//variables para controlar la direccion de la pelota. Las usaremos para sumar constantemente la posicion de la pelota
var xPelotaDir = 1; //positivo = izq a dere   negativo= de derecha a izq
var yPelotaDir = 1;

//Ubicamos la pelota en el centro de la pantalla
colocarXY ("pelota", 290 + ceroX , 190 + ceroY );   
// ancho lienzo 600,  tamaño pelota 20x20  -> (600/2 - 20/2 ) + margen izquierdo
// alto lienzo  400, pelota 20x20 -> (400/2 - 20/2) + margen sup


//funcion para controlar la pelota
     function Pelota() {
        var posX = getX ("pelota"); //Llamamos a la funcion getX(id);
        var posY = getY ("pelota");

        //iniciamos el movimiento
        posX += xPelotaDir; // a la posicion X le sumamos constantemente (+=) el valor en la direccion x (xPelotaDir)
        posY += yPelotaDir;

//deteccion de los límites (bordes) del div. Cuando las condiciones se cumplen la pelota toca una de las paredes
        //para el eje x. TOCA LA PARED IZQ
        if (posX <= ceroX) {    //si se cumple la condicion, si la posicion es <= q ceroX (margen izq del div) 
            xPelotaDir = 1;     // positivo, se mueve de izquierda a derecha

            document.getElementById("puntosJugador").value = puntuacion;

            localStorage.setItem('resultatPunts', puntuacion);
            var resultatEmmagatzemat = localStorage.getItem('resultatPunts');

            alert ( nombre + " has perdut!! \n La teva puntuacio és: " + puntuacion) ;
            puntuacion = 0;
            puntos.innerHTML = 0;
            usuari();
        }

        if (posX >= paredX - 20) {  //si se cumple la condicion,  si la posicion es >= paredX (margen der del div) - tamaño bola
            xPelotaDir = -1;    // negativo, se mueve de derecha a izquierda 

        } 

        //para el eje y
        if (posY <= ceroY ) {   //si se cumple la condicion... si la posicion Y <= ceroY es (margen sup del div)
            yPelotaDir = 1; // positivo, se mueve de izquierda a derecha
        }
        if (posY >= paredY - 20) {  //si se cumple la condicion...  paredY es el margen izq del div - tamaño bola (20)
            yPelotaDir = -1; // negativo, se mueve de derecha a izquierda 
        }

        colocarXY ("pelota", posX, posY);  // colocamos la pelota (id)
     }
//RAQUETA
//variable que nos indica la dirección en la que se mueve. Sobre el eje y
var yDireccion = 0; //direccion del jugador
var xPosicion = 5 + ceroX; //variable fija para el eje x. Nos da la separación respecto a la pared (15) + el margen hasta la pared izq del div

//llamamos a la funcion para colocar el elemento raqueta
colocarXY ("jugador", xPosicion, 160 );     

//FUNCION PARA MANEJAR LA RAQUETA: mover/ parar

function mover(event) {     // Le pasamos objeto (event) 

    var tecla = event.keyCode; // código de tecla
    //evaluacmos la tecla pulsada
    switch (tecla){
        case 38: 
            yDireccion = -1; // la pala sube
            break;
        case 40: 
            yDireccion = 1; // la pala baja
            break;
    }
}

function parar(event) {

    var tecla = event.keyCode; // código de tecla
    if (tecla == 38 || tecla == 40){    // al presionar una de estas teclas
        yDireccion = 0; //se deja de mover 
    }
}

function Raqueta() {
    var posJugador = getY ("jugador"); //obtenemos la posicion y del jugador

    posJugador += yDireccion; // a la posicion del jugador le sumamos yDireccion (operacion de incremento +=)

    //Deteccion de los bordes del div para la raqueta
    if (posJugador <= ceroY) {  //si la posicion  del jugador es menor q el margen superior
        colocarXY ("jugador", xPosicion , ceroY );// la dejamos fija, q no se mueva  colocarXY (id,x,y)
    }
    if (posJugador >= (paredY - 80)) {  //si la posicion raqueta >= 
        colocarXY ("jugador", xPosicion , (paredY - 80 ));
    }
    if  (posJugador >= ceroY && posJugador <= (paredY - 80)) {      // si está en medio de las dos paredes
        colocarXY ("jugador", xPosicion , posJugador );
    }
}

// Deteccion de los choques con la raqueta 
function choque () {

    //condiciones a cumplir para el choque
    if (getX ("pelota") == (getX ("jugador") + 20) ){ // EJE X: si las posiciones en el eje x de pelota y (raqueta + 20 ancho) coinciden 

    if ( (getY("pelota") >=  getY("jugador") ) && ( ( getY("pelota") <=  getY("jugador") + 80))) {  // EJE Y: si a su vez en el eje vertical
            xPelotaDir = 1; //cambiamos la direccion de la pelota (la hacemos positiva)
            document.getElementById("puntosJugador").value = puntuacion;
            puntuacion++;   //cada vez que le damos a la raqueta anotamos un punto
            puntos.innerHTML = puntuacion;

        }   
    }
}

/*  ////////////// funcion Principal del juego.   /////////////////////  */
// Para arrancarlo y añadir las llamadas a las demás funciones

function main() {
    Pelota();
    Raqueta();
    choque();
}
    // esta funcion se encarga de llamar a la funcion main()
setInterval ("main();" , velocidad );
```

Comment: En la funcion `usuari()` dónde defines la variable `puntuacion`?

Comment: Hola @enrique, defino la variable puntuación cómo global fuera de la función.  var puntuacion = 0; //inicializamos la puntuacion en 0  
//guardamos por variables el acceso al DOM de la puntuacion   
var puntos = document.getElementById("puntosJugador");

Comment: Hola @enrique, he editado mi código y lo he puesto al completo. Entiendo que es largo, pero así se interpreta mejor.  Addemás otros usuarios lo pueden editar o reutilizar si quieren.

Comment: Se me ocurre una idea, que no sé si funcionaría, por eso no la propongo como respuesta, pero: ¿Y si creas tres variables en el localStorage?, me explico: Creas la del usuario con el valor de su nombre, la de los puntos con los puntos como tal, y la tercera variable es la que los asocia, haces algo como `localStorage.setItem(localStorage.getItem('nomUsuari'),localStorage.getItem('resultatPunts'))`, así asocias el valor de un usuario con sus puntos, para acceder al dato: `localStorage.getItem(localStorage.getItem('nomUsuari'))`, algo así podría ser interesante..

Comment: La solución que ofrece @Montaycabe no la he probado, pero también parece interesante

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no estas guardando un array sino que estas reescribiendo siempre la mismas dos  variables, por lo que `localStorage.length` siempre te va  a dar 2 (si no guardas mas cosas, claro, porque no discriminas).

Yo creo que lo mas sencillo es que crees un objeto y lo guardes como json en el localstorage en una única variable más o menos así (ojo, no pongo ejemplos literales sino orientativos):

```
var myJSON = JSON.stringify(fronton);
localStorage.setItem("usuarios", myJSON);
```

Puedes comprobar al empezar si la variable "usuarios" en el localstorage existe, en tal caso usas esa informacion:

```
fronton = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("usuarios"))
```

y si  no creas el objeto asi:

```
var fronton = {players: [{nombre: "Jugador 1",puntos: 0}]}
```

y le puedes agregar mas jugadores más o menos asi (en este caso, lo recupero de un campo de texto):

```
fronton.players.push({nombre: $("#name").val(),puntos: puntuacion})
```

Para borrar jugadores, sabiendo su posicion en el array del objeto "players":

```
 fronton.players.splice(posicion, 1);
```